# query params in react router v4

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I use regex for path configuration and it works well,

except that **when I want to use regex as a pattern for query params, it doesn't recognize question mark in path**.

below is my regex pattern.

```
const regPat = /^confirm/signup/validation\?mobile=09\d{9}$/
```

thanks for support :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it doesn't recognize the question mark?

This will match the url slugs along with the query

```
/confirm\/signup\/validation\?mobile=09\d{9}/
```

You can test it here: [regexr share link](http://regexr.com/50m1d)

Comment: exactly. I tested this pattern and I saw that it worked well like just you tried,  but I was just confuse that this regex pattern doesn't work in react router v4 path configuration because it doesn't recognize the question mark.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry I misunderstood. Yeah they talk about that here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/391